# R Parallel pack Error: one node produced an error: no applicable method for 'convergence' applied to an object of class "try-error"

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Recently I've been trying to study the 2-stage DCC model in R by myself. Found an article very helpful: https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-garch-dcc-model-and-2-stage-dccmvt-estimation/

However, I got stuck at the

```
install.packages("rmgarch")
library(rmgarch)
install.packages("parallel")
library(parallel)
data(growthrates)
Dat = growthrates2[, 1:7, drop = FALSE]
# define a DCCspec object: 2 stage estimation should usually always use
# Normal for 1-stage (see below for
xspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = 'eGARCH'), distribution.model = 'norm')
uspec = multispec(replicate(7, xspec))
spec1 = dccspec(uspec = uspec, dccOrder = c(1, 1), distribution = 'mvnorm')
spec1a = dccspec(uspec = uspec, dccOrder = c(1, 1), model='aDCC', distribution = 'mvnorm')
##  aDDC for asymmetric DCC; The distributions supported are the multivariate normal (“mvnorm”) and the multivariate affine NIG (“manig”) and GHYP (“magh”) distributions of Schmidt
spec2 = dccspec(uspec = uspec, dccOrder = c(1, 1), distribution = 'mvlaplace')
spec2a = dccspec(uspec = uspec, dccOrder = c(1, 1), model='aDCC', distribution = 'mvlaplace')

cl = makePSOCKcluster(7)
## stopCluster(cl)
showconnections()


print(class(cl))
multf = multifit(multispec=uspec, Dat, cluster = cl)
```

Every lines of codes were running smooth until the last line of the multifit. 
The error shows:

```
> multf = multifit(multispec=uspec, Dat, cluster = cl)
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: no applicable method for 'convergence' applied to an object of class "try-error"
```

I tried to search that online there was someone said that it could be the presence of n.a. values in the dataset but there was no n.a. values in my dataset.

So what could be the reasons for the error? Thanks

Edit: "dat2" replaced by "Dat" at the last line of codes to avoid confusions.

Comment: What is `dat2`?

Comment: dat2 is growthrates with no "0" values. I input it with other codes not copy paste to here.

Comment: Problem solved. just had the time/date column deleted and it run smoothly.